# Is there any way to align a badge in flutter to the extreme right?

Tags: flutter, badge

[image: Picture of the current output:]

Code i used:

```
Badge(
                              badgeColor: CUSTOM_GREEN,
                              shape: BadgeShape.square,
                              borderRadius: 20,
                              toAnimate: false,
                              badgeContent: Text("Responded",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12)),
                            )
```

Is there any way i can align the badge to be on the extreme right?

Answer (score 0):

Use MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween with Row widget.

```
 Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(children: <Widget>[
                  CircleAvatar(),
                  Column(
                    children: [],
                  )
                ]),
                Badge(
                  badgeColor: CUSTOM_GREEN,
                  shape: BadgeShape.square,
                  borderRadius: 20,
                  toAnimate: false,
                  badgeContent: Text("Responded",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12)),
                )
              ]),
```

Comment: Tried it but doesnt work. Thanks for the response though

Comment: it's depend how you manage your list tile widget, You can also use mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween property of row.